# Is there any issue with the array declared in this Parse cloud code?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud

I am having following code on Parse cloud

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getJournalEntryWeekly", function(request, response) {
var currDate =new Date( request.params.currDate);
var user = request.params.user;
var avgArray = new Array();

for(i = 0;i < 7; i++)
{

 var d1 = new Date(currDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (i+1)); 
 var d2 = new Date(currDate.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (i));
 var query = new Parse.Query("JournalEntry");
 query.greaterThan("createdAt",d2);
 query.lessThan("createdAt",d1);
 query.equalTo("userName",user);

 query.find({
   success: function(results) {

    if(results.length > 0)
    {
    var entry = results[0];
    //response.success(entry.get("level"));
    console.log(entry.get("level"));
   // avgArray.push(entry.get("level"));

    }
    else
    {
     response.error("no entry found");
    }
},
error: function() {
  response.error("no entry found");
}
});
}
response.success(avgArray);

});
```

This code executes console.log statement if 'response.success(avgArray)' line is removed , is there any problem with the array declaration and use ?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `var avgArray = [];` ?

Comment: @Wain tried it same issue , not getting whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `query.find({` you are running an asynchronous request. Your call to `response.success(avgArray);` is after the call to `find` rather than *inside* the callback, so it runs before the query has completed and the cloud function terminates.

Move your call to `response.success(avgArray);` to resolve the issue.